# Como pegar a origem de um formulário em python cgi?

Tags: html, python

Olá, estou usando python com cgi, para meus formulários.
Preciso de pegar o origin para ter certeza que meu site está seguro, mas não encontrei informações sobre isso.
A unica coisa que estou fazendo, por enquanto é recuperar os dados que vem via post ou via get:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import cgi
form = cgi.fieldStorage()

# pego uma opcao do post assim:
nome=""
if "nome" in form:
   nome=form["nome"].value
```

Então, será que alguém sabe qual comando uso pra recuperar a origin(site de onde está vindo o formulário para acessar essa página)?

Answer (score 0):

Resposta curta - mas leia abaixo!!!

```
import os
origin = os.environ.get("REMOTE_HOST")
```

Algumas considerações: CGI puro não é uma tecnologia interessante de ser usada em 2018. Foi implementada nos tempos "pré-web 1.0" - além de problemas drásticos de performance, é de um tempo em que "todas as aplicações web tem que implementar tudo": fazer por si mesmas toda o código de sessão, segurança, verificação de entrada, mapear seus dados manualmente para objetos Python, grava-los no banco de dados (ou outro meio)

Da época em que CGI era usado mais comumente para hoje a complexidade - e formas de ataque à - aplicações WEB foram multiplicadas por mais de 100 vezes.  A título de exemplo, uma requisição CGI cria um novo processo, com um novo interpretador Python, para cada requisição de página via HTTP.  Já há cerca de 10 anos que mesmo usar uma thread do sistema (reusando o interpretador Python  e o processo) é considerado "overkill" - embora ainda seja ok para apps sem muito tráfego.

Entenda o que acontece: os mecanismos de CGI do web server preenchem a variável de ambiente "REMOTE_HOST" com o conteúdo do campo "Origin" do HTTP. (Você pode até chamar `cgi.print_environ_usage()`
 para ver outras variáveis de ambiente interessantes).

No entanto como "mecanismo de segurança" essa variável e *nada* são a mesma coisa.  O campo "Origin" é colocado no cabeçalho http - no funcionamento normal da aplicação, isso é feito pelo navegador do usuário, que preenche o campo com o domínio no site. No entanto, qualquer pessoa conectada a internet pode fazer uma requisição de "post" ou "get" ao seu servidor preenchendo os cabeçalhos de http, incluindo o "origin", como quiserem. Isso na verdade é uma das funcionalidades do protocolo http, pois permite a implementação de APIs.

Ao criar uma aplicação WEB você tem que ter ciência que qualquer coisa que chegue no seu servidor pode vir de qualquer lugar na internet, e com qualquer conteúdo.

A única coisa que é possível garantir é que, em algum ponto, antes de lhe enviar uma resposta, o cliente HTTP fez alguma outra requisição ao seu servidor (por exemplo, para recuperar o html do formulário em si) - isso é feito pelo uso de tokens criptográficos. Mas tenha em mente que todo o código da página está sob controle de terceiros: não se pode garantir nenhuma restrição dos valores enviados pelo cliente, nem validação nem nada: o "navegador" cliente é livre para criar um "POST" completamente arbitrário para sua aplicação.

Ao longo de décadas (décadas depois da criação do CGI, aliás) de aplicações web, os frameworks web foram evoluindo, e incorporando código que ou implementa sozinho, ou incentiva o uso, de boas práticas de segurança. O tipo de "ataque" em que você está pensando, por exemplo, é mitigado pelo uso de "Cross Site Request Forgery" token verification, e é colocado de forma (quase) automática por todos os frameworks em desenvolvimento ativo.  E é um "ataque", diferente de um "POST" arbitrário feito por uma API, por que poderia ser usado para embutir postagens ao seu site a partir de javascript embutido maliciosamente em qualquer outra página na web - assim, um usuário do seu site que visitasse a outra página poderia ter os dados roubados ou adulterados.

Então, a recomendação é: Ok brincar um pouco com CGI para entender os mecanismos. Mas, assim que possível, e especialmente, não ponha nenhuma aplicação no ar: use um framework web como flask, Django, Bottle e Python 3 (Python 2 também é uma tecnologia obsoleta que está para ser completamente aposentada. Se o seu computador for um Linux, Python 3 está disponível simplesmente escrevendo "python3" ao invés de Python)

Comment: esses frameworks de python são muito complexos pra mim, não dá.. Só consigo usar o cgi mesmo, já imaginava mesmo que o origin não seria possivel proteger, mesmo assim, obrigada vou tentar esse comando

Comment: Os frameworks só parecem complexos, se você tentar, sem conehcer o framework, pegar uma aplicação pronta. Eles são grandes - e complexos, por que uma aplicação web funcional precisa de tudo o que eles tem para existir. Não usar um framework significa que, para a sua aplicação ser segura, você vai ter que recriar, no seu código, tudo o que os frameworks fazem. Só que enqunato eles tem 10, 15 anos de trabalho de dezenas de voluntários, você teria que fazer tudo sozinha

Comment: Dito isso: comece do começo, sem pular etapas - faça o tutorial oficial do flask.  Uma aplicação em Flask pode ser mais simples do que uma em CGI.

Comment: Não dá certo, já tentei fazer isso, é muita coisa pra pensar ao mesmo tempo... Eu já tenho maior dificuldade pra usar classes (orientação a objetos), piorou querer que eu use um framework que tem que ficar edita aqui, edita ali, não dá... Sou do tipo programação estratuturada, que faz tudo junto, é muito mais fácil e mais legivel. E também mais divertido impletar a segurança eu mesmo... Mas vc tem razão se eu tivesse capacidade de aprender flask seria legal, mas eu melhor do que ninguém conheço meus limites

Comment: Tenta o flask - com flask _dá_ pra fazer tudo no mesmo arquivo (inclusive os templates de html, podem ser strings Python) - e você pode acessar o banco de dados com os drviers de Python e escrever o sql direto, se o sqlalchemy parecer complicado.

Ai, você vai pondo as coisas a medida que precisar - mas o flask puro, sem usar os formulários e sem sqlalchemy, na verdade pode ser mais simples do que CGI.

No meu perfil tem meu e-mail. qualquer coisa, escreve lá.